# Looping over several variables in data frame summarize and convert the data from long to wide then write out the results as .csv file

Tags: r

I have a very large data set, I would like to summarize it (extract the means) for each individual within each environment for each variable. Then convert the data from long to wide format using Environments as my time variable, then write out the long data for each variable as a .csv file.
Here is what I have done, which work fine outside the for a loop.

```
varlist <- names(pheno)[7:17]

for ( i in varlist)
{
pheno_W<-aggregate(pheno[[i]]~ENV+ENTRY., data=pheno, mean,  na.rm=TRUE)

pheno_L<-reshape(as.data.frame(pheno_W), idvar = c("ENTRY."), timevar = "ENV", direction = "wide")

filename <- paste(i, ".csv", sep="")

write.csv(pheno_L,filename)

}
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

the way you wrote it, `i` is not a variable but a characater (insert `is.character(i)` at the beginning of your loop to see this).

To tell R that `i` is to be read as a variable you can use

```
i=as.symbol(i)   
pheno_W<-eval(bquote(aggregate( .(i)~ENV+ENTRY., data=pheno, mean,  na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635127/dynamic-variable-names-in-r-regressions/53649140#53649140), on different ways to tell R to treat a character as variable in a formula.

Comment: SAFEX: thank you so much --- after applying your suggested modifications-- it gives me this error --- Error in model.frame.default(formula = as.symbol(i) ~ ENV + ENTRY., data = pheno) : 
  object is not a matrix

Comment: @hema Apologies, copied the wrong code! try again with modifixed solution. generally, you help us if you include a minimal reproduceable example. Then I could have tested it before posting the solution and would have spotted the error myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer it does not look very efficient but at least it is working:

```
for ( i in varlist)

{

pheno_W<-aggregate(pheno[[i]]~ENV+ENTRY., data=pheno, mean,  na.rm=TRUE)

colnames(pheno_W)[3]<-noquote(i)

pheno_L<-reshape(as.data.frame(pheno_W), idvar = c("ENTRY."), timevar = "ENV",   direction = "wide")
#m<- paste(i, "avg", sep="")
pheno_L$avg<- rowMeans(pheno_L[,2:8], na.rm = TRUE)
filename <- paste(i, ".csv", sep="")

write.csv(pheno_L,filename)

}
```