# How do I apply an lm function over a list of dataframes referencing the columns by index?

Tags: r

I have 73 equally sized dataframes. All of them have 5cols and a 120rows. I have them stored in a list. I want to run an lm function over all of them using lapply. I want to regress the first column over the next 3 adjacent columns for each dataset in the list. I am having trouble figuring out how to reference columns by index in an lapply function.

I can't use names because all of the col names are different. This is what I tried:

```
my_lms_ESW <- lapply(listDF_ESW, function(x) lm( x[,1] ~ x[,2] 
                                                + x[,3] + x[,4], x))
```

Comment: The second (`data`) argument to `lm` is optional, so if you leave it out (i.e. the final `, x` in your statement) then you should be able to just reference the columns directly in the way that you have done.

Answer (score 2):

in your function(x):

```
lm(
    as.formula(paste(colnames(x)[1], "~",
        paste(colnames(x)[c(2, 3, 4)], collapse = "+"),
        sep = ""
    )),
    data=x
)
```

This assembles a formula object by pasting the names of the columns along with ~ and +.

Comment: note that this is vulnerable to failing if any of your column names are nonstandard, in which case you can include backticks (\`) in the pastes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53649140/1412059

Comment: We usually avoid `as.formula(paste( ..., "~", ...))` in favor of `reformulate()`.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of `lm()` when passed a data frame is to invoke `DF2formula()` which regresses all other columns onto the first column, so in this case you can simply do:

```
lapply(listDF_ESW, \(x) lm(x[-5])
```